# Last character of string not being picked up

Tags: python, arrays, string, list

Trying to solve the problem where I can reverse each word in a string , Since there is no "\0" in python unlike C, My logic is failing to pick up the last character of the string.
Any idea how can this be fixed with not too many changes to the code

```
Input  = This is an example
Output = sihT si na elpmaxe 

import os
import string

a = "This is an example"
temp=[]
store=[]
print(a)
x=0
while (x <= len(a)-1):

    if ((a[x] != " ") and (x != len(a)-1)):
       temp.append(a[x])
       x += 1

    else:
            temp.reverse()
            store.extend(temp)
            store.append(' ')
            del temp[:]
            x += 1

str1 = ''.join(store)
print (str1)
```

My output is truncating the last character

```
sihT si na lpmaxe
```

Comment: You have a condition that specifically excludes the last character.

Comment: You have been writing c for far too long. `print ' '.join(word[::-1] for word in a.split())`

Comment: @pvg if I do this : if ((a[x] != " ") and (x != len(a))) my output truncates the last word completely . output is : sihT si na

Comment: @pvg and for the while loop , if I do this :while (x <= len(a)): I get string out of range error

Comment: It's not clear why you don't want to change your code, but as @Holloway demonstrated, what you are trying to do can be done pythonically in one short line.  Is there a reason to maintain your code?

Comment: I guess I am just too used to do things the C way , but I am new to Python so its a learning curve for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have remove `-1` in both `len(a)-1` and change order in `and` (so when `x == len(a)` it will no try to get `a[x]` which could give `"index out of range"`)

```
while (x <= len(a)):

     if (x != len(a)) and (a[x] != " "):
```

Full version which works for me

```
import os
import string

a = "This is an example"
temp = []
store = []
print(a)

x = 0

while (x <= len(a)):

    if (x != len(a)) and (a[x] != " "):
        temp.append(a[x])
        x += 1
    else:
        temp.reverse()
        store.extend(temp)
        store.append(' ')
        del temp[:]
        x += 1

str1 = ''.join(store)
print(str1)
```

Comment: still getting memory violation "IndexError: string index out of range"

Comment: @Fenomatik did you change order in `and` ?

Comment: I just did , so I am assuming there is an order for condition , from left to right ?

Comment: it has to first check `x != len(a)` and when it will be false then it will not do `a[x]` which gives `"index out of range"`

Comment: It worked perfectly fine , learned there is a left to right conditional check. your answer fixed the bug unlike others who gave me a way to use method.

Comment: `and` , `or` are `"lazy"` - `False and anything` always gives `False` so there is no need to calculate `anything`. `True or anything` always gives `True` so there is no need to calculate `anything`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129075/discussion-between-fenomatik-and-furas).

Comment: This is a pretty awful answer - the problem with the code isn't the off-by-one error but that it's written in a way that trivially enables such errors. For this case, it's easy to use python in a way that makes that particular error impossible - and it's one of the reason to use Python over C to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

As `pvg` suggested, you are excluding the last character yourself. You don't need to check for `x != len(a)-1`, so that you can add the last character in the `temp` string. The last word than can be added once you exit the loop, it will be contained in the `temp` variable. This hint is just to get your code working, otherwise you could do it in a much shorter way in python as suggested by people.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple and no need a extra loop:

```
a = "This is an example"
print(a)
str1 = " ".join([word[::-1] for word in a.split(" ")])
print(str1)
```

input and output:

```
This is an example
sihT si na elpmaxe
```

Comment: People are so fast, let it be there as decoration

Comment: Indeed. Any doubt?@pylang